# VS2010 missing context menu item to "Open in Expression Blend" with Blend 4 installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, integration, contextmenu, expression-blend

I have Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Expression Blend 4 Premium installed on Windows XP.  Blend was installed sometime after VS2010 was.

When I right-click a solution file in VS2010, I'm expecting to see an item "Open in Expression Blend" in the context menu, but I don't.  I wasn't sure if this was supposed to be a feature, but googling around it seems to indicate that it is.

If I'm not dreaming of a non-existant feature, why don't I get this menu item?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not coming even fir the individual Xaml files that you have added in you project?

Comment: That's right. No items in Solution Explorer have the option on my context menu.

Answer (score 0):

try installing [VSCommands 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf) extension. It comes with 'Open in Expression Blend'.

Comment: I had a look at that extension, but it was too obtrusive and I had to uninstall it. It did appear to have the "Open in Blend" option, but only on the project files (even though it appeared to open the solution). On the whole, I found the extension a bit to "yuck" visually, and gave me the impression it wasn't a very well made product. I steer away from these types of extensions, as it's too easy to introduce bad code into my development environment that leaks and interrupts my flow.
Surely VS is supposed to have a supported "Open in Blend" option itself?

Comment: Open In Blend was there with Blend 4 Preview but doesn't seem to work in Blend 4 RTM anymore.

As for VSCommands and being too obtrusive and yuck, would you care to tell us what exactly made you think that way? We are actively working on improvements and your feedback is always welcome (either here or at support@vscommands.com).